# PostgreSQL SQL Order By

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is the subquery in this "order by" clause considered a *[scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES)* or something else (e.g., a *[table subquery](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2036581&seqNum=9)*)?

```
select id, field
  from table1 t1
 order by (select field
            from table1
           where table1.id = (select value1
                                from table2
                               where value1 = table1.id 
                                 and value2 = t1.id) asc
```

The point of confusion for me is the PostgreSQL documentation linked above states a scalar subquery *returns exactly one row with one column.* But in this usage, the row returned by the subquery is not always the same row, but rather differs based on the row returned by the outer query. So a more accurate description, at least when used in this way in an order by clause, might be that it *returns exactly one row with one column **for each row returned by the outer query***.

Follow-up: On further reading, it's clear this is a scalar subquery, though more specifically a *correlated* scalar subquery. [This](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2036581&seqNum=9) notes subqueries can be *correlated* or *uncorrelated*, with the distinction being whether it "refers to and is dependent on values in the outer query". [This](https://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1146-160K/dek1472240802523.html) further clarifies that a *correlated* scalar subquery "returns a single value *for each row* of its correlated outer table set", while a *noncorrelated* scalar subquery "returns a single value to its containing query".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery in an `order by` is a scalar subquery.  It returns one value (at most) for each row in the result set.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon! Upon further reading, if I understand correctly (see above), it is a correlated scalar subquery.

Comment: @JWoodchuck . . . Yes, it is a *correlated* scalar subquery.  But the correlation is not why it is acceptable in the `ORDER BY`, but scalar-ness is why.  On the other hand, a non-correlated scalar subquery would not make much sense (under most circumstances) in an `ORDER BY`.